# Sharepoint workflow 2013 is not triggering automatically

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I created a work flow in sharepoint 2013 after installing the sharepoint sp1 update. But the work flow is not automatically triggered when an item is created. I've enabled the start automatically......... trigger and start manually in the work flow settings. Though it is not triggered automatically i have to trigger it manually from the list everytime. Pls help

Answer (score 0):

What account did you use to publish and run the workflow?

When we create an item using system account, the workflow will not start automatically.

If you want to use system account, please activate “Workflows can use app permissions” site feature through going to site settings->site actions->manage site features. And use App steps in workflow in SharePoint Designer.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-workflo

Comment: Thanks @julie_MSFT. I created the workflow using my account and it's not triggering automatically. Will it work if we add an app step? Please help me

Comment: Yes, please try it. Whether other users occur the same issue? Re-publish the workflow then test again.

Comment: Yes, others also have a same issue, And can i add the app step in that workflow itself?
I mean create the specific work flow with app steps