# How to trigger multiple workflows on a single list automatically

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I have a SharePoint list Request to create a new document. This list has 3 workflows, workflow 1- send approval mail, Workflow 2 - Once approved, Create the document in the Draft library, and Workflow 3- Give the number to the document. These workflows are in Sharepoint Designer 2013. They used to trigger automatically but not anymore. I cannot seem to find the problem.

Comment: Has there been any updates or changes to the environment? This maybe applies to you? https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/284666/sharepoint-workflow-2013-is-not-triggering-automatically

Comment: Thank you, but I checked as you suggested, it is as suggested in the artikel. But still not woking

Comment: Guess you have several more steps like reviewing the eventviewer and ULS logs on the servers, try to deploy a new workflow to a new list to test if they work or if they don't start any more either.